# What belongs together here '年产数百万顿的'?

Tags: meaning

How should I read this: ,形成了年产数百万吨的强大产能。

Is it: A ,形成了  (年产数) 百万吨的  强大产能。or

B ,形成了年产  (数百万吨的)  强大产能。

I believe '数百万‘ = 'several million', but I think '年产数‘ could be 'annual production figure'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be B. If you want to use `年产数` as a phrase, it shoule be

```
形成了年产数为数百万吨的强大产能
```

or

```
形成了年产数达到数百万吨的强大产能
```

BTW: `顿` should be `吨`.